# How to redirect URLs with trailing slash to the corresponding ones without it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller

Spring MVC (3.0) considers URLs with and without trailing slashes as the same URL.

For example:

> http://www.example.org/data/something = http://www.example.org/data/something/

I need to redirect the URL with trailing slashes

> http://www.example.org/data/something/

to the URL without it:

> http://www.example.org/data/something

I need to do this internally the application (so not rewrite rules via Apache, etc).

A way to do it is:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/something/")
public String dataSomethingRedirect(...) {
    return "redirect:/data/something";
}
```

but this has generally 2 problems:

1. too many controllers
2. problem with parameters: like wrong encoding

### Question

Is there a way to intercept all the URLs and in case they have a trailing slash, redirect them to the relative one without slash?

Comment: If one always redirects to the other, aren't they similarly equivalent? The effort involved in achieving this is likely to be high. If your concern is entirely cosmetic, it simply can't be worth it.

Comment: They're not equivalent when it comes to relative url links

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You could list all the rewrite rules you need in your web configuration

If there aren't many of those, you can configure redirect views like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/my/path/", "/my/path")
      .setKeepQueryParams(true)
      .setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT); 
}
```

### Or you could create a custom [HandlerInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

But interceptors occur before requests are mapped to a specific `Controller.action` and you've got no way of knowing Controllers and actions in that context.

All you've got is HTTPServlet API and request+response; so you can:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://example.org/whitout-trailing-slash");
```

### The answer you don't want to read

This behavior (URL with trailing slash = URL without it) is perfectly "valid" when considering HTTP. At least this is the default behavior with Spring, that you can disable with `useTrailingSlashMatch` ([see javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseTrailingSlashMatch-boolean-)).

So using rewrite/redirect rules on the front-end server could a solution; but again, I don't know your constraints (maybe you could elaborate on this and we could figure out other solutions?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about using HandlerInterceptor with my version of "preHandle" (and actually I did it). The problem is due to "SEO" reasons as Google ranking for same pages with & without "/" is not considered good.

Comment: So you're considering dropping that approach for SEO reasons? That's a good idea - and I think SEO is only one reason amongst many...

Comment: Ok, it's a good reason I didn't know. But your visitors will probably write your home url only. The rest of requests usually come from your own links.

Comment: FYI, there is a JIRA request to add a HandlerInterceptor for this case (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8473).

Comment: "*This behavior (URL with trailing slash = URL without it) is perfectly "valid" when considering HTTP.*". No, `http://example.org/blabla` and `http://example.org/blabla/` (or even `http://example.org/blabla//`) are distinct URLs as far as HTTP is concerned. A number of servers will treat them as the same, but that's an implementation choice for the dispatch mechanism. Apache Httpd has it on by default (`DirectorySlash On`), but that's an option.

Answer (score 11):

I think you best option would be to do this before entering in Spring web's servlet, using UrlRewriteFilter. This will ensure that your redirect rules would not impact your controllers.

Please note that you write the rules in your .war project, not in an apache with mod_rewrite.

[Go here](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) for the library's project on googlecode.

in the urlrewrite.xml write :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.1//EN" "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.1.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule match-type="regex">  
      <note>Remove trailing slash</note>
      <from>^(.*)/$</from>
      <to type="redirect">$1</to>
    </rule>  
</urlrewrite>
```

In the web.xml of your application, add :

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>confPath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Beware, the declaration order of the filters in the web.xml is important, so try to declare this one before anything from spring.

Of course, this is but a fraction of what UrlRewriteFilter can do.

Regards.

Comment: good tip! actually you might want to specify the from as <from>^(/.*)/$</from> . This regex would skip domain names redirect in case of a trailing slash as domain names are considered a 'special case' (www.domain.com and www.domain.com/ should both return 200) and you can't/don't have to redirect them

Comment: as google suggest a 301 should also be preferred .. <to type="permanent-redirect">$1</to>

Answer (score 3):

This usually works for me with URLRewriteFilter in Spring.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.2//EN" 
 "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.2.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
         <note>Remove trailing slash for SEO purposes</note>
         <from>/**/</from>
         <to type="permanent-redirect">%{context-path}/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if spring 3.0 had this, but spring 3.1 [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) allows you to set a "useTrailingSlashMatch" property.  By default it is true.

I think switching it to false would solve your issue, however it would affect ALL mappings handled by RequestMappingHandlerMapping across your application... so you may have a fair amount of regression to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Brian Clozel: I don't think is a good idea to do what you want. So, why you need it?

Anyway, I think the simplest solution is to write a custom `javax.servlet.Filter`. So, no Spring dependency. If the request URL ends with slash you just have to redirect to the same url without it. But caution:

- All parameters (GET and POST) must be added as GET parameters. Are you sure that your application is *method agnostic*?
- You can have some problems with encoding. In the filter you can encode POST parameters to the required encoding. But the default encoding for GET parameters is not configured in your application. Is configured in server.xml (if Tomcat) and default value is ISO-8859-1.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on SEO, I think it is important to make a distinction.

If the URL that finished in the trailing slash exist, is indexed in the search engines and there are links on Internet, a permanent redirection (301) is required as Uddhav Kambli says. The standard redirection (302) will be better than having a duplicated URL, but is not good enough.

However, if the URL never existed, it is not indexed on Internet and there are no external links, the URL does not exist. Therefore a 404, page not found, is a better fit.

WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.1//EN"  "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.1.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule match-type="regex">
        <note>Remove trailing slash</note>
        <from>^(.+)/$</from>
        <set type="status">404</set>
        <to>null</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

And in order to complete the configuration ...

add to WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>confPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this can also be handled much more simply by using an ErrorViewResolver bean somewhere in your @Configuration:

```
@Autowired
private DefaultErrorViewResolver defaultErrorViewResolver;

@Bean
ErrorViewResolver errorViewResolver() {
    return new ErrorViewResolver() {
        @Override
        public ModelAndView resolveErrorView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus status, Map<String, Object> model) {
            if(model.containsKey("path") && !model.get("path").toString().endsWith("/")) {
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+model.get("path") + "/");
            }
            return defaultErrorViewResolver.resolveErrorView(request, status, model);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm not sure if this is good or bad practice, but it is effective in my circumstance, and does exactly what I need it to do for an arbitrary path 'foo': respond with a 302 redirect to /foo/ when you request /foo and respond as it should when you request /foo.