# Spring-MVC 3.1: How to map URLs with a trailing slash?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm converting a legacy servlet application over to Spring 3.1.  In the process some URLs are now obsolete.  We've had some problems with our network that will not be resolved anytime soon.  My boss doesn't want to trust that their redirects will always be operational.  So, she asked me to put my own redirects into the webapp.

All works great, except that if a URL has a trailing slash Spring 3.1 will not find the Controller class function that handles it.

http://blah.blah.blah/acme/makedonation    gets found, mapped and handled

http://blah.blah.blah/acme/makedonation**/   does not**

Here is the controller class I am using to handle my legacy URLs

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.*;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Controller
public class LegacyServletController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LegacyServletController.class);

    // Redirect these legacy screns "home", the login screen via the logout process
    @RequestMapping({"makeadonation","contact","complain"})
    public String home() {
        logger.debug("started...");
        return "redirect:logout";

    }// end home()  

}// end class LegacyServletController
```

I Googled around and found this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711392/spring-mvc-urls-with-trailing-slash-redirection) that offers several suggestions, but I am new to Spring and do not understand enough of it to implement some of those suggestions.   This one in particular sounds like it would be good fit with my needs:

> spring 3.1 RequestMappingHandlerMapping allows you to set a
>   "useTrailingSlashMatch" property. By default it is true. I think
>   switching it to false would solve your issue,

Would anyone give me a basic example of how to that, quote me a URL that has such an example ( I had no luck with Google ) or point me to a better idea?

Thanks much in advance
Steve

Comment: I've saw such solution `@RequestMapping(value = {"/search/", "/search"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should configure your bean in context.xml,and set property. 
 or you can refer to [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120192) or spring doc section [16.4](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping)

example configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="true">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you mean my *-servlet.xml or my web.xml?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring's Java `@Configuration` you can also just declare a `@Bean` like this:

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping useTrailingSlash() {
    return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping() {{ setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true); }};
}
```

Comment: That wont work if you have <mvc:annotation-driven/>. This is how you fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912329/exact-requestmapping-with-spring