# Exact RequestMapping with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have the following in Spring

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

However Spring automatically adds mappings for /hello/ as well as /hello.*. How do I do an exact URL match?

Only /hello should work, anything else should 404

Comment: strange... R U sure you try to use `/hello/foobar` and not `/hello?foo=bar`?

Comment: /hello/foobar would fail but /hello.foobar works but shouldn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning off suffix matching (`useSuffixPatternMatch`) on `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` will solve your problem, but doing so is actually not so easy, if you use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your configuration (instead of manually wiring all the necessary infrastructure beans). In this case defining an additional bean of type `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` won't have any effect.

You have two options:

1. Remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` expanding it to an equivalent set of bean definitions where you can apply the `useSuffixPatternMatch` setting.
2. Keep `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` as it is, and use a much easier workaround described here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9371. This basically adds a `BeanPostProcessor` which retrieves the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean created by the mvc namespace, and sets the above mentioned flag.

There is also [another ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10163) requesting that it should be much easier to customize the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` created by the mvc namespace without applying hacks like above. You can consider voting on this ticket.

Comment: spring 4 solution:
<mvc:annotation-driven>
         <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 3.1/3.2, then you can try this without commenting or deleting

### Write a post processor

```
public class MvcConfigurationPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

   @Override
   public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
         ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) bean).setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
      }
      return bean;
   }

   @Override
   public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      return bean;
   }

   @Override
   public int getOrder() {
      return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
   }

}
```

---

use the above post processor in xml config.

```
<bean class="com.beanprocbug.melia.MvcConfigurationPostProcessor" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off suffix matching like so:

```
<bean name="handlerMapping" class="...annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"></property>
</bean>
```

See [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) for details.