# url pattern for exact matches on url with no extension

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

How would you make it so that `/url` works but `/url.html` or `/url.jsp` fails? I'd like to setup my pattern to only accept exact matches that have no extension.

Currently in web.xml I use

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>DispatchServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and on my controllers I use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

but that allows any extension to be mapped to my controllers so long as 'url' is contained in the requested path. I would like extensions or incorrectly appended characters to fail. Is there a way to do this without parsing the URL string programmatically for each controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exact RequestMapping with Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912329/exact-requestmapping-with-spring)

Comment: See this [answer][1]. Maybe this will work for you?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15920913/2839073