# How to make controller mapping more specific

Tags: java, spring

I have defined my Spring controller mapping as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/common")
public class GenericController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse test2(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ModelMap model) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("###############");
        return null;
    }
```

Now, when I start my WL then I can see logs as:

```
- Mapped URL path [/common/test2] onto handler 'genericController'
- Mapped URL path [/common/test2.*] onto handler 'genericController'
- Mapped URL path [/common/test2/] onto handler 'genericController'
```

And needless to say above logs are true, so I can access my application as `http://localhost:7001/MyWeb/forms/common/test2`, `http://localhost:7001/MyWeb/forms/common/test2.do` and `http://localhost:7001/MyWeb/forms/common/test2/`.

I do want this much exposure of mapping, I want that it should only be accessible as `http://localhost:7001/ITDWeb/forms/common/test2`.

I tried to search for option but couldn't find any. Anybody any idea on how to make controller mapping more specific?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912329/exact-requestmapping-with-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own custom configuration

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false); // no prefix matches
        handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false); // no affix matches
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```