# Exact @RequestMapping in Spring rest API

Tags: spring, rest, exact-match

I have URL @RequestMapping(value = {"/sessionkey"}, method = {RequestMethod.PUT}, produces = {"application/json"}) in my spring rest API. but it accepts special character, like "/sessionkey#?".

I want my API to accept only exact match the "/sessionkey" URL and should not accept any special character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exact RequestMapping with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912329/exact-requestmapping-with-spring)

Comment: I am using spring rest API not MVC. How do i match the request URL.

Comment: Is this from a browser?

Comment: No, I want to restrict at API level.