# how to add RequestMappingHandlerMapping and ResourceHandlers to a springMVC configuration class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver()   {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
}


}
```

I have an issue with maping URLs with a trailing slash,similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560916/spring-mvc-3-1-how-to-map-urls-with-a-trailing-slash). so i want to add `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class, but based on the instruction i get [there](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/111171-configuring-requestmappinghandlermapping-when-using-mvc-annotation-driven) i need to **extend** `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`  class and implement `requestMappingHandlerMapping()` method, but unfortunatly i have already extended WebMvcConfigurationSupport  class for resource's mapping. Is there any way i could add requiest mapping handler to my class?

**NOTE**: i am using Spring version 3.1.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't get from your question why you can't use [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html). If by what you mentioned *"...unfortunatly i have already extended `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class for resource's mapping..."* you rather meant that you've already extended the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you should be aware that `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` exposes exactly the same method.

Anyways, following should be a working java config for Spring MVC 3.1 version

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping hm = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        hm.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return hm;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Overriding requestMappingHandlerMapping using WebMvcConfigurationSupport, may turn off your spring boot's default configurations. A better way could be to use WebMvcRegistrations as,

```
@Configuration
static class CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new MyRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebMvcRegistrations` instead of `WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

And since Spring Boot 2.0.0 you could use WebMvcRegistrations directly

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig  {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcRegistrations webMvcRegistrationsHandlerMapping() {
        return new WebMvcRegistrations() {
            @Override
            public RequestMappingHandlerMapping getRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
                return new CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the same solution, perfect !