# Programatically define RequestMappings for a custom Spring Boot starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot starter project that defines controllers programmatically based on the existence of certain types of beans. In the auto configuration class I defined a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` where I register the handlers programmatically similar to the following:

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping customRoutes(ApplicationContext context) {
    var handlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    findTargetBeans(context).forEach((name, bean) ->
        var getMapping = RequestMappingInfo
                    .paths("/" + name)
                    .methods(RequestMethod.GET)
                    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .build();
        handlerMapping.registerMapping(getMapping, createHandler(), getHanderMethod());
    );
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

This seems to build just fine, but when I try hitting the registered paths, I get a 404 response. Am I missing something? Do I need additional configuration to make this programmatic routing to work? I've been looking at old questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5758504/404604), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30402453/404604), but none of the answers work for me.

Comment: Do `"/" + name` is a valid path ?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid path.

Comment: Are those beans annotated with @Controller/@RestController ? because if you have a class without such annotation but with @RequestMapping on methods - it will not work.

Comment: I just tried annotating the controller with `@RestController` and that still didn't work. I create the controller beans during `postProcessBeanFactory`; I'm not sure if that somehow affects the mapping...

Comment: by any change are you using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.x ?? if yes this might affect you https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28874