# Trailing slash is not inserted in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Tomcat in Spring Boot is not inserting the trailing slash after context name at URL.

It should be done automatically by server case it was not specified.

Example:
`/user` would be changed to `/user/` by server

Does anyone have any idea how to enable it?

Thanks

Comment: Ever been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supposed to insert the trailing slash.

It only does that in the case of the contextRoot (which in a Spring Boot application is usally /, so going to http://your.server.here:8080 will redirect to http://your.server.here:8080/)

What is your use case for the redirects?

In case you want this functionality, it should be quite trivial to add a filter that would do the redirects for you.

Check out the answers on this question for how to do it [Spring MVC: urls with trailing slash redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711392/spring-mvc-urls-with-trailing-slash-redirection)

Comment: I noticed for example in Jboss 7.1 when I access an url: "http://domain.com/test" it redirects to  "http://domain.com/test/", but in Spring Boot it does not happen. I wonder to know why it happens?

Comment: Indeed domain.com/test and domain.com/test/ are actually two different urls.


Application servers tend to redirect from domain.com/test to domain.com/test/ when test is the contextRoot of an application (makes handling cookies and such quite a bit easier).

Comment: How to remove trailing slash at ROOT URL?