# Spring-boot rest api. Truncate trailing slash

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, request-mapping

I have a `spring-boot` rest api.

In my `application.properties` I have:

```
server.port=8100
server.contextPath=/api/users
```

There's a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class UserService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<UserJson> create(@RequestBody UserJson userJson) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When I call:

`POST http://localhost:8100/api/users/` **notice the trailing slash** (with user's json) - `create` method executes fine.

But when I call:

`POST http://localhost:8100/api/users` **without trailing slash** (with user's json) - I receive `405` error:

`{ "timestamp": 1520839904193, "status": 405, "error": "Method Not Allowed", "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException", "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported", "path": "/api/users/" }`

I need my URL without trailing slash, just `.../api/users`, and why it's being treated as `GET` method?

Comment: Looks like your HTTP server is rewriting requests without the trailing slash and sending a redirect, substituting GET for POST.  Check your server config.

Comment: @JimGarrison What configs are you referring to? I start my app as `mvn spring-boot:run`, so it's embedded Tomcat. I don't have any additional configs.

Comment: Hmm... based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32098801/18157) it looks like it's not designed to do that redirect.... so this is beyond my expertise. Sorry.

Comment: I found the answer from here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258671/331946

Comment: @htshame Remove the "update" part + add it as an answer!

Comment: @JacobvanLingen makes sense. Done!

Answer (score 1):

If I change `server.contextPath` to `server.contextPath=/api` and `@RequestMapping` in my RestController to `@RequestMapping("/users")` everything works fine. `create()` method is being called with and without of trailing slash at the end on the URL.

Comment: Any particular reason you set the contextPath at all? A request mapping for /api/users would be what I would do. Actually I would do /api/users/v1 because future you will thank you for introducing API versions sooner rather than later.

Comment: I have a pretty big app, so we need a contextPath for the common API URl prefix. I also have /v1 and /v2 prefixes, but they are on the @RestController levels now.