# How to redirect URL with forward slash in spring boot and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I am trying to redirect URL with forward slash at the end of the requested URL.
For example, if a user clicks on about page then the requested URL would be like this http://localhost:1209/about

I need to redirect the URL with trailing slashes

http://localhost:1209/about/

Previous approach :

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/about"},method= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
     public ModelAndView about(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
     ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(WebUrl.about);
     return modelAndView;
}
```

I tried as below :

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/about/"},method= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
         public ModelAndView about(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/about/");
         return modelAndView;
    }
```

Below is the script for adding trailing slash to coming url:

```
<script>
    var url = document.URL;
    var lastChar = url.substr(-1);
    if(lastChar != '/'){
        url = url + '/';
        window.location.href = url; 
    } 
</script>
```

**What should I do to redirect URL with or without trailing slashes?**

[image: Screenshot of error]

[image: Screenshot to display current url]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect URLs with trailing slash to the corresponding ones without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711392/how-to-redirect-urls-with-trailing-slash-to-the-corresponding-ones-without-it)

Comment: No, I tried through this link also. But did not solved my problem. and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  is derecated now.